# Is it important to rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a repo, with development branch. Two developers work on their branches, b1 and b2 both taken from development branch. Both work and when done, keep pushing changes to origin. Then these branches are merged into development at origin (Bit-Bucket).

I want to ask if it would be important form them to Rebase their branches with development after every merge? Or just keep going with more and more commits and pushes until done with the feature? What should be correct strategy here?

Comment: Rebase is usually nicer and cleaner, but whether to systematically use it depends on the context and it is a matter of *opinion*

Comment: this link can help you understand the industry standard i guess https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'correct' strategy.

They can rebase their b1/b2 branch onto development branch each time the development branch has a new commit. This has two advantages:

1. Fix merge conflicts immediately and in small chunks.
2. Developer is sure that his code works with whatever was pushed to the remote in the time that his feature was being developed.

Or, they can branch off development branch, implement their feature on b1/b2 and do no rebasing until they are done with the feature. This has one advantage:

1. No hassle with merge conflicts etc. while they are working on their feature, keeping them more focused on their task at hand.

however this also has 2 disadvantages

1. They need to rebase at the end when their feature is done. They don't know how many commits were made to development branch in the meantime, potentially making this a huge task - the more commits to rebase on, the more potential merge conflicts, the more confusing it can be, the more work it is.
2. It's possible that code that was merged into development branch in the meantime breaks code that they were depending on in their feature.

It really depends on how you/they want to work. Do they want their workflow to not be disturbed? -> rebase once, at the end. Do they want reassurance that their code will work with whatever was pushed in the meantime? -> rebase often.

Comment: It must also depend on the project size and specifics. If the project is huge and tends to change dynamically then you better rebase more often, because as Tim said - after 2 month of work there is a good chance that you will spend a week looking for information about how to correctly rebase and what should/shouldn't be kept. On the other hand - if there are two developers working on separate parts of a project - there is no reason to rebase all the time, especially if you can directly communicate and plan / coordinate your work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your workflow is questionable.

This is some valid workflow:
1. Developer start to work on functionality F1
2. Developer creates branch f1 from development branch.
3. Developer makes changes to branch f1.
4. When developer finish functionality f1 then:
   - developer merge branch f1 into development  branch
   - developer delete branch f2

Another scenario when rebasing is recomended is:
1. Developer A start to work on functionality F1
2. Developer A creates branch f1 from development branch.
3. Developer A makes changes to branch f1.
4. Developer B makes changes to development branch and that change is important to have into branch f1
5. To get changes from development branch into f1 developer A rebase branch f1 with development branch
6. Developer A makes more changes to branch f1.
7. When developer finish functionality f1 then:
   - developer merge branch f1 into development  branch
   - developer delete branch f2

So merging functionality into parent branch in general is done when functionality is finished. After that that branch is best to delete and create new one when starting to develop next functionality. Rebasing in that context is good to get changes from parent branch while still development is in progress.